# FosElasticaBundle: How to search using multiple keywords?

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

this is working for me ok: `$results = $finder->find('muj*');`

but when I try `$results = $finder->find(array('muj*', 'hom*));` I get this:

> SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all
>   shards failed; shardFailures {[qTMnzJeGTu-YVumR2xLW1Q][search][1](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Finder/FinderInterface.php):
>   RemoteTransportException[[Starshine][inet[/192.168.1.83:9302]][search/phase/query]];
>   nested: SearchParseException[[search](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Finder/FinderInterface.php): from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source
>   [{"0":"muj*","1":"hom*","query":{"match_all":{}}}]]]; nested:
>   SearchParseException[[search](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Finder/FinderInterface.php): from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No
>   parser for element [0]]]; }{[LgfD_idnTtmv3JHcMPnkmw][search][0]:
>   SearchParseException[[search][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse source
>   [{"0":"muj*","1":"hom*","query":{"match_all":{}}}]]]; nested:
>   SearchParseException[[search][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No
>   parser for element [0]]]; }{[vpaWi0XRT8eo7UYtgFFsag][search][3]:
>   RemoteTransportException[[Clint
>   Barton][inet[/192.168.1.83:9301]][search/phase/query]]; nested:
>   SearchParseException[[search][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse source
>   [{"0":"muj*","1":"hom*","query":{"match_all":{}}}]]]; nested:
>   SearchParseException[[search][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No
>   parser for element [0]]]; }{[LgfD_idnTtmv3JHcMPnkmw][search][2]:
>   SearchParseException[[search][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse source
>   [{"0":"muj*","1":"hom*","query":{"match_all":{}}}]]]; nested:
>   SearchParseException[[search][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No
>   parser for element [0]]]; }{[qTMnzJeGTu-YVumR2xLW1Q][search][4]:
>   RemoteTransportException[[Starshine][inet[/192.168.1.83:9302]][search/phase/query]];
>   nested: SearchParseException[[search][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source
>   [{"0":"muj*","1":"hom*","query":{"match_all":{}}}]]]; nested:
>   SearchParseException[[search][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No
>   parser for element [0]]]; }]

For me it is strange since the docs say that `find()` admits [an array as parameter](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Finder/FinderInterface.php).

Comment: Maybe should be an associative array?

Comment: @DonCallisto I have tried this:`$results = $finder->find(array('1' => 'muj*', '2' => 'hom*'));` but the error is the same.

Comment: Yes, I mean, maybe the "keys" have to be setted correctly. I don't know anything about FOSElasticaBundle so I'm only trying to guessing looking to log error messages